# Adobe Illustrator: white cracks appears on objects when zooming in and out

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, zoom

I'm having this problem in Illustrator when I zoom in and out, there appears to be a bunch of white cracks that changes shapes, but stays there when not zooming. Looks something like this:[[image]

[image]

Been having this problem for quite a while and can't seem to figure out why. I've tried disabling animated zoom in settings, but still happens here and there.

Please help if anyone knows how to fix this issue!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Looks like a graphics card problem. Try updating your graphics card driver.

Comment: @BillyKerr or backdating it in fact

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/141327/horizontal-white-lines-in-illustrator-but-not-in-export